# Nearley grammar recognizes same non-terminal symbol multiple times under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, grammar, lexer, nearley

Given the following nearley code:

```
   @builtin "whitespace.ne"

   @{%

   let numberedParams = {
       3: 45
   };

   const lexer = require("moo").compile({
       comment: /\(.*?\)/,
       expstart: /\[/,
       expend: /\]/,
       paramstart: '#',
       equals: "=",
       operator: /\*\*|\+|\-|\*|\/|OR|XOR|AND|MOD|EQ|NE|GT|GE|LT|LE/,
       function: ['ATAN','ABS','ACOS','ASIN','COS','EXP','FIX','FUP','ROUND','LN','SIN','SQRT','TAN','EXISTS'],
       linenumber_command: 'N',
       command: /[ABCDFGHIJKLMPQRSTUVWXYZ]/,
       float: /[0-9]*\.[0-9]+/,
       int: /[0-9]+/,
       ws: /[ \t]+/,
       EOL: {match: /(?:\r\n?|\n)/, lineBreaks: true }
   });

   // Converts from degrees to radians.
   Math.radians = function(degrees) {
     return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
   };

   // Converts from radians to degrees.
   Math.degrees = function(radians) {
     return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
   };

   function empty(d) {
       return null;
   }

   function logid(prefix) {
       return function (d) {
           console.log(prefix, d);
           return d;
       };
   }

   // Appends to list
   function append(d) {
       if (Array.isArray(d[0])) {
           return d[0].concat(d[2]);
       }
       return [d[0], d[2]];
   }

   function getparam(d) {
       return numberedParams[String(d[1])] | 0.0;
   }

   // Returns the result of one parsed line
   function processLine(d) {

       logid("processLine")(d);

       if (d[0] != null) {
           return [];
       }

       if (d[2] != null) {
           return [d[2]].concat(d[4]);
       }

       if (! Array.isArray(d[4])) {
           return [d[4]];
       }

       return d[4];
   }


   %}

   @lexer lexer

   line ->
       block_delete:? _ linenumber:? _ line_items EOL {% processLine %}

   block_delete ->
       "/" {% id %}

   linenumber ->
       %linenumber_command int_or_float {% function (d) { return {command: d[0].value, value: d[1]}; } %}

   line_items ->
       line_item {% id %}
       | line_items _ line_item {% append %}

   line_item ->
       comment {% id %}
       | parameter_setting {% id %}
       | word {% id %}

   word ->
       %command _ number {% function (d) { return {command: d[0].value, value: d[2]}; } %}

   parameter_start ->
       %paramstart {% id %}

   parameter_setting ->
       parameter_start parameter_index _ %equals _ number {% function (d) { return {command: d[0].value + d[1], value: d[5]}; }  %}

   comment ->
       %comment {% function (d) { return {command: 'COMMENT', value: d[0].value}; } %}

   gcode_expression ->
       "[" _ expression _ "]" {% (d) => d[2] %}

   expression ->
       logical_expression {% id %}

   logical_expression ->
       comparative_expression {% id %}
       | logical_expression _ "AND" _ comparative_expression {% (d) => d[0] && d[4] %}
       | logical_expression _ "OR" _ comparative_expression {% (d) => d[0] || d[4] %}
       | logical_expression _ "XOR" _ comparative_expression {% (d) => ((d[0] && !d[4]) || (!d[0] && d[4])) %}

   comparative_expression ->
       additive_expression {% id %}
       | comparative_expression _ "EQ" _ additive_expression {% (d) => d[0] == d[4] %}
       | comparative_expression _ "NE" _ additive_expression {% (d) => d[0] != d[4] %}
       | comparative_expression _ "GT" _ additive_expression {% (d) => d[0] > d[4] %}
       | comparative_expression _ "GE" _ additive_expression {% (d) => d[0] >= d[4] %}
       | comparative_expression _ "LT" _ additive_expression {% (d) => d[0] < d[4] %}
       | comparative_expression _ "LE" _ additive_expression {% (d) => d[0] <= d[4] %}

   additive_expression ->
       multiplicative_expression {% id %}
       | additive_expression _ "+"  _ multiplicative_expression {% (d) => d[0] + d[4] %}
       | additive_expression _ "-"  _ multiplicative_expression {% (d) => d[0] - d[4] %}

   multiplicative_expression ->
       power_expression {% id %}
       | multiplicative_expression _ "*"  _ power_expression {% (d) => d[0] * d[4] %}
       | multiplicative_expression _ "/"  _ power_expression {% (d) => d[0] / d[4] %}
       | multiplicative_expression _ "MOD"  _ power_expression {% (d) => d[0] % d[4] %}

   power_expression ->
       function_expression {% id %}
       | power_expression _ "**"  _ function_expression {% (d) => Math.pow(d[0], d[4]) %}

   function_expression ->
       number {% id %}
       | "ATAN" _ gcode_expression _ "/" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.degrees(Math.atan(d[2], d[6])) %}
       | "ABS" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.abs(d[2]) %}
       | "ACOS" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.degrees(Math.acos(d[2])) %}
       | "ASIN" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.degrees(Math.asin(d[2])) %}
       | "COS" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.cos(Math.radians(d[2])) %}
       | "EXP" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.exp(d[2]) %}
       | "FIX" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.floor(d[2]) %}
       | "FUP" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.ceil(d[2]) %}
       | "ROUND" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.round(d[2]) %}
       | "LN" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.log(d[2]) %}
       | "SIN" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.sin(Math.radians(d[2])) %}
       | "SQRT" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.sqrt(d[2]) %}
       | "TAN" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.tan(d[2]) %}
       | "EXISTS" _ gcode_expression {% (d) => Math.cos(d[2]) %}

   number ->
       primary {% id %}
       | _ "-" number {% (d) => d[2] * -1 %}
       | _ "+" number {% (d) => d[2] * 1 %}

   primary ->
       int_or_float {% id %}
       | gcode_expression {% id %}
       | parameter_expression {% id %}

   parameter_expression ->
       parameter_start parameter_index {% getparam %}

   parameter_index ->
       int {% id %}
       | gcode_expression {% id %}
       | parameter_expression {% id %}

   int ->
       %int {% (d) => parseInt(d[0]) %}

   int_or_float ->
       int {% id %}
       | %float {% (d) => parseFloat(d[0]) %}

   EOL ->
       %EOL {% empty %}
```

When I run nearley-test to test my compiled parser I get the following results:

Command:

```
printf "(Commentwithoutspaces)X[2**[2+5]]\n" | nearley-test gcode.js -q
```

Result:

```
processLine [ null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [ { command: 'COMMENT', value: '(Commentwithoutspaces)' },
    { command: 'X', value: 128 } ],
  null ]
```

So far so good, next test:

```
printf "(Comment with spaces)X[2**[2+5]]\n" | nearley-test gcode.js -q
```

Result:

```
processLine [ null, null, null, null, { command: 'X', value: 128 }, null ]
processLine [ null, null, null, null, { command: 'X', value: 128 }, null ]
processLine [ null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [ { command: 'COMMENT', value: '(Comment with spaces)' },
    { command: 'X', value: 128 } ],
  null ]
```

It looks like it recognizes the X command twice without the comment, and then once with the comment. This only happens when there are spaces inside the comment, which puzzles me...

Now if i test it with a comment that contains spaces at the end of the line, I get:

```
printf "X[2**[2+5]](Comment with spaces)\n" | nearley-test gcode.js -q
```

Result:

```
processLine [ null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [ { command: 'X', value: 128 },
    { command: 'COMMENT', value: '(Comment with spaces)' } ],
  null ]
```

So it seems that the error only happens when I start the line with a comment that contains spaces, which is strange...

Does anyone know what I can do to get a more consistent behaviour? I mean what can I do to make the parser recognize the command and the comment once for each occurence regardless of spaces inside the comment and regardless of the comment is before or after other items on the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that if I removed optional whitespaces from the non-terminal named line and added them to a "lower level" non-terminal it works as intended. The changed non-terminals now looks like this:

```
line ->
    block_delete:? linenumber:? line_items EOL {% processLine %}

linenumber ->
    _ %linenumber_command int_or_float _ {% function (d) { return {command: d[1].value, value: d[2]}; } %}
```